# Is assigning to ref parameter of method an atomic operation?

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety

I know that assigning object reference is generally atomic when for example we are assigning to field. But does this hold true when we are assigning to `ref` parameter?

```
void Method(ref Class1 obj)
{
    var newobj = new Class1();
    obj = newobj; // is this assigment an atomic and thread safe operation?
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That depends: is `Class1` genuinely a `class` (or `interface`, or `delegate`)? If it is a `struct`: it may be non-atomic (size being one major factor that affects this); *reference* updates, however, are always atomic; that is guaranteed by the language specification. As for "thread safe" - that is more complex - it depends on how the other values are reading/writing the field. For example, it is not guaranteed that other threads will notice the swap immediately, unless they are doing volatile reads.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The assignment is self-contained (especially since you are assigning a memory address). You can't be sure though that another thread isn't changing the variable a split second later (so you can't be sure `obj == newobj` directly after `obj = newobj`), but you can be sure your value isn't overwritten.

In cases like `List<T>` you have this risk since one method call can lead to multiple object changes in the back.